Mapping an S3 bucket to a Windows drive causes Java file existence check to fail
I’ve mapped an Amazon S3 bucket to a Windows drive called D:\ using MountainDuck
I have a Java application that verifies that a given path exists. It does this using the java.nio.Files API Files.exists() method.
The application can verify the existence of any folder on my local Windows machine that I specify but it cannot verify any bucket or object on the S3.
Can anyone explain why that is and how I can refactor my code to read and write from the S3 when it’s mapped to an S3 bucket?
if (!Files.exists(path)) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException(“Specified path does not exist”);
}


I see from this question that mapping an S3 bucket to a Windows drive is a bad idea but if one had to, how would you replicate what the Java code above is doing but in an S3 context

Are you saying that this call works for files but fails for folders, or that it fails for both?

I've only tried it for folders at the moment (and it fails).

Try it for a file. If it works for files but not for folders then a possible cause is that S3 doesn't have an actual folder hierarchy; it simply has objects in a flat keyspace which represents a logical folder hierarchy. That said, I'd be surprised if an S3 mount didn't actually present typical file and folder semantics.


how would you replicate what the Java code above is doing but in an S3 context

Essentially all you need to do is this:
AmazonS3Client client = ...;
String bucketName = "...";
ObjectMetadata meta = client.getObjectMetadata(bucketName, path);

The getObjectMetadata call will fail if the path does not exist (throwing an Exception)
Ref: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3Client.html#getObjectMetadata-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-

Thanks. And if I wanted to copy a file from the bucket to a Windows folder I would also have to use the S3 client? I can't use Files.copy()?

Correct.  You'd use a method such as https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3Client.html#getObject-java.lang.String-java.lang.String- which returns an S3Object and in that you can obtain an InputStream so you can read bytes into a local file.
